# Auto-generate a interface implementation for a dbus interface in Python?

Tags: python, code-generation, dbus

Are there any tools that can read a set of DBus XML files and create a set of representative Python classes? Any embedded code generated for catching related events & initialising the interface would also be a benefit.

Currently the project I am working on is duplicating loads of lines of code from a large exported api. Such a tool would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [code generation tools in telepathy-python](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/telepathy/telepathy-python/tree/tools). Telepathy's spec XML format is a superset of the standard D-Bus introspection format; you should be able to feed plain-ish introspection XML, possibly with a few extra annotations, to those tools.